# Priority queues in GO

Tags: algorithm, go, priority-queue

Can anyone explain this to me:
I want to implement a priority queue in GO (interface implementation got from [link](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example__priorityQueue), but for the lowest priority)

My code:

```
pq := make(PriorityQueue, 0)

pq.Push(&Item{value: 0, priority: 0})

heap.Init(&pq)

fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))

item := &Item{value: 1, priority: 10}
pq.Push(item)
item = &Item{value: 2, priority: 20}
pq.Push(item)
item = &Item{value: 3, priority: 5}
pq.Push(item)

fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))

// Output:
&{0 0 -1}
&{1 10 -1}
&{3 5 -1}
&{2 20 -1}
```

Why it not outputs:

```
&{0 0 -1}
&{3 5 -1} 
...
```

Comment: Hi Jus, I see that you have not accepted the answer yet. Can you clarify what do you need so we can better elaborate an answer ?

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR** use `heap.Push(...)` and `heap.Pop(...)` to add and remove from your queue and preserve order.

The problem is in your setup. You should not directly push or pop from your queue and expect it to be ordered. Calling `heap.Init(&pq)` will sort the entire heap, so you can load in stuff and order everything at once.

For your use case, you should be using the heap utilities for push and pop. When you are adding to the queue, use `heap.Push(...)` rather than `pq.Push(...)`

```
pq := make(PriorityQueue, 0)

heap.Push(&pq, &Item{value: "0", priority: 0, index: 0})
item := &Item{value: "1", priority: 10, index: 1}
heap.Push(&pq, item)
item = &Item{value: "2", priority: 20, index: 2}
heap.Push(&pq, item)
item = &Item{value: "3", priority: 5, index: 3}
heap.Push(&pq, item)

fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
```

Subsequent push and pops will always be ordered this way. Since every item is ordered on insertion, you don't need to call `heap.Init(&pq)`. This is closer to an implementation that would be used in a production environment where pushes and pops are interspersed.

Answer (score 1):

The way this particular priority queue is implemented, you should call `heap.Init` *after* you've pushed your items into the queue, as the original example demonstrates.

```
pq := make(PriorityQueue, 0)

pq.Push(&Item{value: "0", priority: 0, index: 0})
item := &Item{value: "1", priority: 10, index: 1}
pq.Push(item)
item = &Item{value: "2", priority: 20, index: 2}
pq.Push(item)
item = &Item{value: "3", priority: 5, index: 3}
pq.Push(item)

heap.Init(&pq)

fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
fmt.Println(heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item))
```

Will print the items in priority order, as expected.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i need pop some items before new items will be pushed (smth like this):
heap.Init(&pq)
for {
   heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
   ...
   pq.Push(item)
}

Answer (score 0):

First note that you said you expected the lowest priority first, but the highest the number is, the highest the priority is. So it should be 20, 10, 5, 0.

In the docs:

> Take the items out; they arrive in decreasing priority order.

I just took your data and put it into the example in the doc page (the link you provided).
Check it out:  [play.golang.org/p/7GyYgJ-HAwi](https://play.golang.org/p/7GyYgJ-HAwi)

The main difference is the `heap.Init(&pq)` location.

Edit: @[Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky) provided the answer while I was typing mine.